# iPhone App AppStore submission with SessionM SDK

Tags: ios, iphone

I have added SessionM SDK with mPoints to my iOS app. When I submitted it to review I checked YES for Advertising Identifier (IDFA) question.

But the App was rejected with reason "We found that your app uses the iOS Advertising Identifier but does not include ad functionality."

I have checked the code with **grep -r advertisingIdentifier .** and got match in **SessionM-SDK/libSessionM.1.14.6.a**  (SessionM SDK)

And now I have a question - should I select YES for Advertising Identifier (IDFA) question or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got approve for my App.
Correct answer is - you should check YES for Advertising Identifier (IDFA) question, because SessiomM SDK really uses it.
But some Apple's reviewers can't find advertisement even if it on main screen under the nose.
In this case simply provide more info about advertisement, and how user can find it.

Answer (score 0):

You does not need to check Yes for Advertising Identifier(IDFA) question.
it is only require when you have functionality in application to show ads via using Google ad, Chart boost library etc.

Comment: Have you used SessionM in your Apps? I have tried to answer NO, but itunesconnect detects advertisingIdentifier in App binaries, and I can't submit the App with such answer.  And advertisingIdentifier was detected with grep -r. SessionM really use it, because there is a field with IDFA of test devices on app settings web site.

Comment: No brother i didn't used it in my apps